# Special enumeration layout

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

How can I reproduce the following list layout using the `enumitem` package? (I did it just manually with a table):

[image]

Note that the numbers should be aligned at the left border of the body (not total body).

I tried to tweak the different parameters of `enumitem` but everything was a mess.

Comment: Are the numbers outside of the body or within?

Comment: Within the body. If you want: draw a tangent the first ones and you get the boundary of the body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possible way -- others may work of course too!

The labelling itself is quite easy with the `label*=...` syntax to use the parent level label.

The alignment is not so easy. All must be left aligned with respect to the left margin, so for deeper levels, the leftmargin must be all `0pt` and the label width equal for all levels. The `30pt` is just an arbitrary value here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\setlist[enumerate]{align=left}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{labelwidth=30pt,leftmargin={\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{labelwidth=30pt,leftmargin=0pt,label*={\arabic*}}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{labelwidth=30pt,leftmargin=0pt,label*={.\arabic*}}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{labelwidth=30pt,leftmargin=0pt,label*={.\arabic*}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \blindtext
\begin{enumerate}
\item \blindtext
\begin{enumerate}
\item \blindtext
\begin{enumerate}
\item \blindtext
\item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a shorter way, using a `\newlist` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength{\mylabelwidth}
\setlength{\mylabelwidth}{40pt}


\newlist{leftenum}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[leftenum]{align=left,labelwidth={\mylabelwidth},topsep=5pt,leftmargin=0pt,label*={\arabic*.}}
\setlist[leftenum,1]{leftmargin={\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{leftenum}
\item \blindtext
\begin{leftenum}
\item \blindtext
\begin{leftenum}
\item \blindtext
\begin{leftenum}
\item \blindtext
\item \blindtext
\end{leftenum}
\end{leftenum}

\end{leftenum}
\end{leftenum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `topsep` distance should be redefined to be constant at all levels?

Comment: @pluton: Well, you're right most likely.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, align=parleft, itemindent=0pt, labelsep=\widthof{9.9.9.9\quad}, leftmargin=0cm}
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=\thesection.1, leftmargin=\widthof{9.9.9.9\quad}}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{label=\theenumi.\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate, 3]{label=\theenumii.\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate, 4]{label=\theenumiii.\arabic*}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}
Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \lipsum[2]
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item\label{test} \lipsum[2]
          \item We can see from \ref{test} cross-references work.
                \begin{enumerate}
                  \item\label{test} \lipsum[3]
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}%
```

[image]